# Prevent blank screen (locking) in gnome-shell while watching videos

Tags: 17.10, lock-screen, gnome-shell

When my computer (running ubuntu 17.10) is idle for 5 minutes it goes blank and lock the screen. This is perfect, but while watching a video with flash, mpv, ... I would expect the power saving feature to turn off, or better, the video player to tell gnome-shell that there's activity. It's better cause this way it the video player crash, the screen blanking/locking did not change.

In MPV there's an heartbeet-cmd to tell the computer it's active, this seams perfect, but is there a command to tell gnome-shell that there is activity, preventing it from power saving?